# How can I display a text perday in my android app

Tags: java, android

I'm building a quotes app and i want the app to display a text on the startup page of my app, but i cant seems to get it right. Here is the code i tried...

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {
    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }
    final Handler h = new Handler();
    TextView lv, nam, cate;
    String randomQuotes, qNames, category;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        lv = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.quotes);
        nam = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        btn = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.share);
        //List of quotes
        ListView allQuote = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.liv);

        //Display a text on screen in every 24hours
        final Random rand = new Random();
        h.post(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                int x = rand.nextInt(AllQuotes.LIFE.length);
                lv.setText(AllQuotes.LIFE[x]);
                nam.setText(AllQuotes.NAMELIFE[x]);
                h.postDelayed(this, 60000 * 24);
            }
        });


        return rootView;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is it that you're trying to do (the expected result) and what's the result now?

Comment: You need to create a random number form the date. try seeding the random with the current date.

Comment: if you want your app run every 24 hours and show a random quote use **AlarmManager** , create a service and go on , but if you want your app show a new quote per day after it began to run you can save date and time of this quote in a place then on tomorrow run retrieve this date and time if it was about 24 h show the new quote

Comment: I think there is a easier way to show a quote for per day.

When you show a quote for per day, you can save your date and quote in your DB then you can compare your current date and saved date in your DB. In this way the app doesn't show the same quote for different dates.

Comment: Save the last quote index in the SharedPreferences along with the date so you can know the last quote and the day.

Comment: @manabreak I'm trying to display a text perday in my app

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to update the quote from another thread because the user wont be looking at the startup page of your app for 24 hours. Just get a qoute according to the current date every time the start up page is created.

```
//Display a text on screen in every 24 hours
//seed the random with the current date to get new random number only if the date is changed.
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int seedVal = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)*12*30+cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)*30+cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
Random rand = new Random(seedVal);
rand.nextInt(AllQuotes.LIFE.length);
lv.setText(AllQuotes.LIFE[x]);
nam.setText(AllQuotes.NAMELIFE[x]);
```

Comment: Dont know how the seedVal works but dont this have a probability of showing the same quote before having showed all?

Comment: Yes, but using plain random also has the same tendency, doesn't it? Maybe the quotes should be put in some sort of shuffled list and got incrementally according to the date modulus the number of items.

Comment: I was thinking op wants to show it one per day secuentially so the first will not show again until the last, for that a SharedPreferences approach should be better.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want it to run every 24 hours, the math to convert it to milliseconds is `60000 * 60 * 24`. `60000 * 24` will give you 24 minutes.
2. You should be using [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/scheduling/alarms.html) for such long intervals.