# How to display a textview perday from strings arrays

Tags: java, android

I've been working on this app for a while, and i'm almost done with it. But the only thing that is delaying me is displaying different textview per-day. Please help, how can i achieve this? Here are the codes i have tried...

```
    try{
            rand.wait(System.currentTimeMillis() + 60 * 1000 * 60 *24);
            int quo = rand.nextInt(MyQuotes.BIB.length);
textView.setText(MyQuotes.BIB[quo]);

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }
```

Everytime i tried the above code, rather than showing a post daily, it will only show the the first array string. Which is position 0.

Comment: do you want to show text from random index of array (daily) each 24 hours ? ya?

Comment: Would using a Calendar work? Like, on your onCreate/onResume you check what day of the year it is, and then using that value to initiate different  Strings from a string-array based on the value of the day-of-year?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display a text perday in my android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36478650/how-can-i-display-a-text-perday-in-my-android-app)

Comment: What was wrong with your previous question?

Comment: @AndreasEvjenth I have thought of that too, but the length of strings in the array is more than 31(month) and less than 365(year). So if the Calendar started counting the number of days, and reached a number that is more than the length of my array. My app would crashed.

Comment: @cricket_007 I didn't get a solution.

Comment: @DevMike You could use the modulo operator like so: ` day-of-year % array.length` . That would give you the numbers from 0 up to the length of your array, and then restart at the beginning again when the day of year is greater than your array.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the issue, as I can't see the rest of your code, but you need to share the Random() instance across the whole class if you are calling the method from somewhere else:

```
public class Numbers {
    Random randnum;

    public Numbers() {
        randnum = new Random();
        randnum.setSeed(123456789);
    }

    public int random(int i){
        return randnum.nextInt(i);
    } }
```

another issue may be that you need to set the seed

```
Random generator = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `strings.xml` entry like this

```
<string name="day_20160502">This is May 5th, 2016</string>
```

Then you can load it in Java like so on that day.

```
// some textview
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd", Locale.ENGLISH);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
String date = fmt.format(c.getTime());

int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("day_"+date, "string", getPackageName());
if (resId > 0) {
    text.setText(resId);
} else {
    Log.e("DailyMessage", "message for " + date + " not found");
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for my late responds, the above code doesn't work. What i need is code that can display a random text daily just like the BibleKJV app does. [https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hmobile.biblekjv&hl=en](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hmobile.biblekjv&hl=en)

Comment: The above code does work. I don't post answers without trying them. What about it doesn't work for you?

Comment: Oh! sorry for that. Maybe i should elaborate on what i meant. The code doesn't do what i expected.

Comment: And why not? You can define a long list of strings in the `strings.xml` and if the timestamp matches the current day, then that string will be displayed. That is how I interpreted what you wanted.